# I need help extracting/replacing text from another text vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, streamreader

I have a text file with a web page source code. I want to search for the title of a manga. (I'm creating a manga downloader)

this is the source code view:source:http://www.mangahere.co/manga/jitsu_wa_watashi_wa/

the title of the manga is in this line:

```html
<h1 class="title"><span class="title_icon"></span>SHOKUGEKI NO SOMA</h1>
```

I want to extract only the 
SHOKUGEKI NO SOMA
part, but i don't know how.

I can search all lines of the text file but only extract the complete line, how can I separate it?